# For loop behaves strangely

Tags: c++

I have a simple `for` loop , which prints out [actually it must , but it doesn't] all numbers from `1` till `365`` (a year).

so , here is it :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 365; i++)
    {
         cout<<i<<endl;
    }
}
```

So the output must be:

> > 1
> >     .
> >     .
> >     .
> >     365

but it's like that:

> > 70
> >     .
> >     .
> >     .
> >     365

---

P.S There aren't any errors at compilation & execution.

Comment: What is your compiler/how are you compiling it? Can you give an example of exact output?

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't using a console that is truncating the output to some number of lines, dropping the first few?  The code you have above is perfectly correct.

Comment: @templatetypedef that seems likely. ddacot, are you using linux? You could pipe the output to `less` (or `more`) to check that it is outputting correctly. Or redirect the output to a file.

Comment: Also try redirect output to file and you will see, that it  prints ok. You can do that like this from your command processor: `program > file.txt`

Comment: @anthony-arnold  GNU Gcc Compiler (Mingw).

Comment: @templatetypedef may be, i observed that when i "cout" the numbers without "endl" or "\n" , i mean inline, it works fine, but when i insert "cout" or "\n" (to display each number in a new line ) it's showing as above.

Comment: @anthony-arnold no , i'm not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the code. Are you using Windows command prompt?

Your buffer size might not be long enough and the output is getting cut off. Right click on the command prompt title bar > properties > height and increase it

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the output  is just getting scrolled up, try outputting the values to a file, or try adding another line wherein the user is forced to enter a key value like "Press enter" before the next line is printed.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works correctly, but your console window can only display 295 (365 - 70) lines at a time. This means that only the last 295 lines of output will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, it looks like a console related issue, I don't know what do you use to connect. Try changing the cout line to: `cout<<i<<" ";` and see that it prints everything.